# Difficulty activating 3 touch gesture recognizer in iOS app

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, multi-touch, touchesbegan

I have an app that uses gesture recognizers quite a bit. From the studying I have done, I have found that there is the touchesBegan method of recognizing a gesture, and then there are gesture recognizers, which should be more slick.

The problem I am running into is that the gesture recognizers aren't nearly as responsive or accurate as the touchesBegan method, but are a lot easier to implement, which is obviously why I am using them. If I want to have a 3 finger gesture detected with a gesture recognizer, it is quite difficult because I have to press down my 3 fingers at the EXACT same time, or else it won't fire. This is in contrast to the touchesBegan method that just knows how many fingers you have down at any point.

Am I missing something with the implementation of this seemingly nice gesture feature that is making it not very responsive? I have set the max and min touches to 3, is that incorrect?

Please help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you need to press at the exact same time is because, by default, only one gesture recognizer can be recognized at a time. So once you press one finger down that recognizer automatically blocks the other two.

Try implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and using:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not sure if this will solve the issue or not but it might.

Cheers.